# Capture which step of an animated system cursor is being shown on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to capture as a bitmap the system cursor on Windows OSes as accurately as possible.
The provided API for this is to my knowledge GetCursorInfo, DrawIconEx.

The simple chain of actions is:

- Get cursor by using GetCursorInfo
- Paint the cursor in a memory DC by using DrawIconEx.

Here is how the code looks roughly.

```
CURSORINFO  CursorInfo;

(VOID)memset(&CursorInfo, 0, sizeof(CursorInfo));
CursorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(CursorInfo);

if (GetCursorInfo(&CursorInfo) &&
    CursorInfo.hCursor)
{
    // ... create here the memory DC, memory bitmap

    boError |= !DrawIconEx(hCursorDC,   // device context
        0,              // xLeft
        0,              // yTop
        CursorInfo.hCursor,     // cursor handle
        0,              // width, use system default
        0,              // height, use system default
        0,              // step of animated cursor !!!!!!!!!
        NULL,               // flicker free brush, don't use it now
        DI_MASK | DI_DEFAULTSIZE);  // flags

    // ... do whatever we want with the cursor in our memory DC
}
```

Now, anyone knows how I could get which step of the animated cursor is being drawn (I need the value that can be then passed to the istepIfAniCur parameter of DrawIconEx...)? Currently the above code obviously always renders only the first step of an animated cursor.

I suspect this can not be easily done, but it's worth asking anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a Windows API that discloses the current frame of the cursor animation.  I assume that's what you're after: the look of the cursor at the instant you make the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are missing a step.

You need to create a bitmap to select into your device context otherwise your bit map is just a single pixel.

See CreateCompatibleBitmap in the MSDN documentation:

```
HBITMAP CreateCompatibleBitmap(
  HDC hdc,        // handle to DC
  int nWidth,     // width of bitmap, in pixels
  int nHeight     // height of bitmap, in pixels
);
```

With DrawIconEx the UINT istepIfAniCur parameter allows you to choose which frame to draw if it is an animated cursor.

It says it there in your comments :

```
0,  // step of animated cursor
```

Comment: Hi David,

I need to know which step of the animated cursor is being drawn so that I can pass that value to DrawIconEx. The comment about creating the DC is replacing all the code about creating the DC, bitmap, selecting the bitmap. That is not the problem.

Comment: Hmm.  Almost a different question.  I would look at some of the system hook functions.  But I doubt it will be there.

Comment: If you somehow manage to succeed in figuring out the current frame then you will be disappointed to find that DrawIconEx will not work on animated cursors that don't exist as a file on the disk.  This restriction also generally extends to accessing cursors from other applications. I spent a lot of time working on this for the Wine project and I discovered that you need to use GetCursorFrameInfo() to properly obtain frames from all the different types of animated cursors.

Comment: @Compholio Btw, do you know the info/parameters for GetCursorFrameInfo?

Comment: @Nicke Manarin Yes, see here:
[https://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/user32/cursoricon.c?!v=wine-2.17#1924](https://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/user32/cursoricon.c?!v=wine-2.17#1924)